# Perl - Regex - Group Capturing

Tags: regex, perl, hex

I'm having some trouble performing a search and replace with capture groups.

I'm creating 3 groups and trying to replace the 1st and 3rd while keeping the second intact.  The actual result is giving me the output with the 1st and 2nd groups correctly replaced while the 3rd is not replaced.

Here's what I've tried:

```
perl -p -e 's|(\x80\xbb)(.{4,})(\x00\x00\x00)|\xc6\x83$2\x00\x00\x01|g' "$1" > "$1.tmp"
```

Input: \x80\xbb`\xef\x00\x00\x00

Expected: \xc6\x83`\xef\x00\x00\x01

I'm not the best at regex so please help me out.  I'm open to answers involving sed as well.

Real contents:

```
\x81\x00\x00\x00\x80\xbb`\xef\x00\x00\x00u!L\x89<$H\x8d\x15\x91\xec\x12\x00L\x89\xefL\x89\xf6H\x8bM\xc8L\x8bE\xd0M\x89
```

xxd:

```
0x000073ff  80bb 60ef 0000 0075 214c 893c 2448 8d15  ..`....u!L.<$H..                                                   
0x0000740f  91ec 1200 4c89 ef4c 89f6 488b 4dc8 4c8b  ....L..L..H.M.L.                                                   
0x0000741f  45d0 4d89 e1e8 5700 0000 c783 2c09 0000  E.M...W.....,...                                                   
0x0000742f  0000 0000 f20f 1005 652b 1200 0f29 8330  ........e+...).0                                                   
0x0000743f  0900 0048 b800 0000 0000 00f0 bf48 8983  ...H.........H..
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that the representation is in hex.

Comment: Good first Q, as you have sample input, expected output, current output and ... gasp, some code!. I've removed the bash tag, as it is not relevant. (probably not he shell tag either ;-/!) . Keep posting and Good luck.

Comment: Not so good: The shown code cannot transform the given input to the alleged actual output.

Comment: What did you use to generate the "real contents"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code you preserve only two sequential bytes in substitution, one capture group is sufficient.

Following code demonstrates how you can convert hex string to binary value, do required substitution and output binary as a text string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($in,$out);

$out = $in = pack 'H*', '8100000080bb60ef00000075214c893c24488d1591ec12004c89ef4c89f648';
$out =~ s!\x80\xbb(.{2})\x00\x00\x00!\xc6\x83$1\x00\x00\x01!;

say 'in:  ' . unpack('H*',$in);
say 'out: ' . unpack('H*',$out);
```

Output

```
in:  8100000080bb60ef00000075214c893c24488d1591ec12004c89ef4c89f648
out: 81000000c68360ef00000175214c893c24488d1591ec12004c89ef4c89f648
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think any groups get replaced, at least when I try. The problem is `.{4,}` which means "at least four characters", but there are only two of them: `\x60\xef`.

Or, if your input is really the hex representation, remove the `\x` from the code: in double quotes, `\x60` represents the character `` ` ``, not the digits `6` and `0`. They are represented by `60` without any prefix.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Test::More;

my $in = "\x80\xbb\x60\xef\x00\x00\x00";
(my $out = $in) =~ s/(\x80\xbb)(.{2,})(\x00\x00\x00)/\xc6\x83$2\x00\x00\x01/g;
is $out, "\xc6\x83\x60\xef\x00\x00\x01";

my $in2 = '80bb60ef000000';
(my $out2 = $in2) =~ s/(80bb)(.{4,})(000000)/c683${2}000001/g;
is $out2, 'c68360ef000001';  #                   ~~~~
```

Note the `${2}0` to prevent interpreting the `0` as part of the variable name.

Comment: Thanks @choroba.  I've ran the perl test script and it passes.  Nice thought on the 2 characters.  For some reason, I'm not having the same result when I'm performing the regex on a file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the file contents in a hex dump, e.g. with `xxd`.

Comment: Thanks again @choroba.  I will update the input with the correct one.  I'm very sorry.  Could you please take another look at the updated input?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please, paste the actual output of `xxd` if you can't paste the contents of the file. Use code formatting so whitespace doesn't disappear.

Comment: Probably want `/s` in case one of the two bytes is `0A`.